# Scikit learn for predicting likelihood based on two values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

New to python, building a classifier that predicts likelihood of vaccination if trust in government (trustingov) and trust in public health (poptrusthealth) from the dataset is greater than a certain percentage. Not sure how to get both as classes.

UPDATE: Concatenated the dataframe values, but why is the accuracy of the model 1.0?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

df = pd.read_csv("covidpopulation2.csv")
print(df.head())
    99853  8254  219  0.649999976  0.80763793
0   99853  8254  219         0.65    0.807638
1   48490  4007  227         0.49    0.357625
2  190179  8927  107         0.54    0.853186
3  190179  8927  107         0.54    0.853186
4  190179  8927  107         0.54    0.853186

print(df.describe())
              99853           8254           219   0.649999976    0.80763793
count  1.342500e+04   13425.000000  13425.000000  13425.000000  13425.000000
mean   3.095292e+05   20555.570056    225.864655      0.473157      0.684484
std    5.070872e+05   28547.608184    218.078176      0.184501      0.167985
min    1.225700e+04      26.000000      2.000000      0.000000      0.357625
25%    5.456200e+04    1674.000000     28.000000      0.370000      0.563528
50%    1.581740e+05    8254.000000    148.000000      0.490000      0.660156
75%    2.992510e+05   29575.000000    453.000000      0.630000      0.838449
max    2.234475e+06  119941.000000    621.000000      0.770000      0.983146

df = pd.read_csv("covidpopulation2.csv", na_values = ['?'], names = ['covidcases','coviddeaths','mortalityperm','trustngov','poptrusthealth'])

print(df.head())
   covidcases  coviddeaths  mortalityperm  trustngov  poptrusthealth
0       99853         8254            219       0.65        0.807638
1       99853         8254            219       0.65        0.807638
2       48490         4007            227       0.49        0.357625
3      190179         8927            107       0.54        0.853186
4      190179         8927            107       0.54        0.853186

print(df.describe())
         covidcases    coviddeaths  mortalityperm    trustngov  poptrusthealth
count  1.342600e+04   13426.000000   13426.000000  13426.00000    13426.000000
mean   3.095136e+05   20554.653806     225.864144      0.47317        0.684493
std    5.070715e+05   28546.742358     218.070062      0.18450        0.167982
min    1.225700e+04      26.000000       2.000000      0.00000        0.357625
25%    5.456200e+04    1674.000000      28.000000      0.37000        0.563528
50%    1.581740e+05    8254.000000     148.000000      0.49000        0.660156
75%    2.992510e+05   29575.000000     453.000000      0.63000        0.838449
max    2.234475e+06  119941.000000     621.000000      0.77000        0.983146

df.dropna(inplace=True)
In [212]:
print(df.describe())
         covidcases    coviddeaths  mortalityperm    trustngov  poptrusthealth
count  1.342600e+04   13426.000000   13426.000000  13426.00000    13426.000000
mean   3.095136e+05   20554.653806     225.864144      0.47317        0.684493
std    5.070715e+05   28546.742358     218.070062      0.18450        0.167982
min    1.225700e+04      26.000000       2.000000      0.00000        0.357625
25%    5.456200e+04    1674.000000      28.000000      0.37000        0.563528
50%    1.581740e+05    8254.000000     148.000000      0.49000        0.660156
75%    2.992510e+05   29575.000000     453.000000      0.63000        0.838449
max    2.234475e+06  119941.000000     621.000000      0.77000        0.983146

all_features = df[['covidcases',
                   'coviddeaths',
                   'mortalityperm',
                   'trustngov',
                   'poptrusthealth',]].values
all_classes = (df['poptrusthealth'].values + df['trustngov'].values)
willing = 0 
unwilling = 0
label = [None] * 13426

for i in range (len(all_classes)):
    if all_classes[i] > 0.70:
        willing += 1
        label[i] = 1
    else:
        unwilling = unwilling + 1
        label[i] = 0

print(willing)
print(unwilling)  

all_classes = label

from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
all_features_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(all_features)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
np.random.seed(1234)
(training_inputs,testing_inputs,training_classes,testing_classes) = train_test_split(all_features_scaled,all_classes,train_size = 0.8,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 1)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
clf.fit(training_inputs, training_classes)
DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
print(clf)
DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
print('the accuracy of the decision tree is:',clf.score(testing_inputs, testing_classes))
the accuracy of the decision tree is: 1.0
import pydotplus
from sklearn import tree
import collections
import graphviz
feature_names = ['covidcases','coviddeaths', 'mortalityperm','trustngov',
                 'poptrusthealth']
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, feature_names = feature_names, out_file =None, filled = True, rounded = True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
colors = ('turquoise','orange')
edges = collections.defaultdict(list)
for edge in graph.get_edge_list():
    edges[edge.get_source()].append(int(edge.get_destination()))
    
for edge in edges:
    edges[edge].sort()
    for i in range (2):
        dest = graph.get_node(str(edges[edge][i]))[0]
        dest.set_fillcolor(colors[i])
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to do regression or classification?

Comment: Trying to do classification with a decision tree :)

Comment: Could you show us samples data of what you have in X and what you have in y? Maybe something like 5 lines of data? Do you have some example y data? I do not see them in your code. Without target/label/y data you cannot train a supervised learning  model.

Comment: If label is your y is has two values 0 and 1 which will be the classes. Just use it with the DT model

Comment: You have duplicate and not useful lines : DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
You shuld also do a train_test_split of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this makes no sense from a machine learning point of view. Your label is **directly** created from the input features. That's why the model accuracy is 100%.

Here is your final classifier (without needing any machine learning):

if trustingov + poptrusthealth > 0.7 predict 1, otherwise predict 0.

Comment: Right There is no real need of ML in this case. it can make sense, if you build your own labels, and/or if it is just an exercice. But it is easier just to apply the test to your data to calculate the result directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible to have 100% accuracy with training data, as the ML algorithm know them.

You have to apply your ML to data not used during the learning phase. It is usually done by splitting data into a training data set and a test data set.

Then you train/fit the ML with train data only. Then test it and calculate accuracy on test data. The test data result/Accuracy will tell you if your ML is well trained and working.
Unused test data is important to do a good ML test. So you will find unbiased accuracy of it.